# Value 0E-16 Coming in S3 parquet files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am calculating a field called as net amount using sql query in my glue job.Whenever I store the result in s3 bucket then for 0 values I get 0E-16.Please find the below screenshot.

[image]

which is causing problem when I am trying to read the data from athena.In athena the datatype for the field defined is double(32,16).Does anybody know what is the problem here and for 0 netamont how we can store the value as 0.000000000 rather than 0E-16